# Delete an image programmatically after loaded in pictureBox completely in C#

Tags: c#, zip, picturebox, delete-file, unzip

I have an image file named image1.jpg in picture folder. This image file is protected by zip and the password is 1234. I need to load this image to my C# winform application; So I have to unzip this image, load it and then delete the image1.jpg again. My problem is that my C# application doesn't show the image when I delete it even after loading the image. If I remove "File.Delete(...." line as you see, It shows the image and there is no problem.

```
//Unzip a zip file protected and overwrite if needed
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Pictures" + "\\image1.zip"))
{
    zip.Password = "1234";
    zip.ExtractAll(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Pictures\\", Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
}



pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Pictures" + "\\image1.jpg";


File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Pictures" + "\\image1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imagePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Pictures" + "\\image1.jpg;
pictureBox1.LoadCompleted += (s, e) => File.Delete(imagePath);
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = imagePath;
```

Comment: That's right. But there is a little problem when it wants to delete the image in folder. Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Asus\Picture\image1.jpg because it is being used by another process.

Comment: pictureBox1.LoadCompleted never fire for me. I used: private void pictureBox3_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("pathToImage.jpg");
        }